# How to correctly redirect output of ls -d */?

Tags: bash

Rather new to command line, so bear with me.

I'm supposed to be finding directories in `/usr/local` that end with a number. I've managed to list just the directories with:

```
ls -d */
```

but when I try using anything with via piping:

```
find -name
grep
look
```

there's no output shown. I've even tried just using the '*' wildcard for searching, but nothing shows up.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What exactly did your command line look like? You cannot use `find -name` to filter the stdinput.

Comment: My most recent attempt was:  ls -d */ | tr '/' ' ' | find -type d -name '*.[0-9]'

Comment: `find` does not read its standard input; the `ls -d ... | tr ...` is irrelevant to it.  You also need to provide `find` with one or more names as the locations to search.  You might have done better with: `find $(cd /usr/local; ls -d */ | tr '/' ' ') -type d -name '*[0-9]'`.  It isn't a good solution, but it would mostly work.

Answer (score 1):

The find command should be able to do what you want, and from the looks of it you have it just about right:

```
find / -type d -name <directory_name>
```

That will look for any directory with the name you specify from the root directory. If you ran the command as you show above I think the flaw was you were not specifying the directory to start your search. You can use the man page as well if you need any other parameters to specify:

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find

Comment: Ah, sorry. I guess I was a little unclear. I'm not looking for one specific directory, just any of the directories in /usr/local that end with a number.

Comment: You can replace the `/` with any given directory. `find "/path/to/some/dir/*[0-9]" -type d -maxdepth 1`

Comment: Try this:

find /usr/local -type d | sed 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/

Comment: You shouldn't need to run `grep` or `sed` on the output of `find` for the given requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /usr/local -type d -name '*[0-9]'
```

This does it all in one; looks under `/usr/local/` for directories where the name ends with a digit (and implicitly prints the result).

Your code using `ls` might need to look like:

```
cd /usr/local || exit 1
ls -d */ | grep '[0-9]/$'
```

This will list directories with a slash at the end of the name, so you need to search for the names where there's a digit followed by the slash and the end of the name.  One difference between this and the `find` command is that `ls` only lists directories immediately in `/usr/local` whereas `find` will search down directory hierarchies.  If you don't want `find` to search down the hierarchy, say so:

```
find /usr/local -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*[0-9]'
```

(If you place `-maxdepth 1` at the end, some versions of `find` get snotty about it and complain.)

Answer (score 0):

```
find "/path/to/some/dir/*[0-9]" -type d -maxdepth 1
```

Comment: This has some problems.  The shell won't expand the `"/path/to/some/dir/*[0-9]"` into a list of names because of the double quotes, so the chances are high that `find` will report 'no such file or directory' for it.  To achieve what you're after, use the name that the question gives (`/usr/local`) and specify `-name '*[0-9]'` as one of the filters.  Then you're in business.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -l /path/to/some/dir | grep "^d" | awk '{print $9}'
```

Comment: (1) Generally, you only need one answer.  You could have added this as an alternative to your other answer, with commentary to explain why you'd choose between the options.  (2) This runs into problems if directory names contain spaces. (3) This does not for directory names to end with a digit. (4) The question gives `/usr/local` as the directory to search; you could have used that instead of `/path/to/some/dir`. (5) You really shouldn't need to run three commands where one would do.

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in /path/to/some/dir/*; do \
    if [[ -d $file ]]; then \
        echo $file; \
    fi \
done
```

Comment: A third answer...you were busy...This does not filter for names ending with a digit.  Other than that, it works reasonably well, using the shell's native abilities to generate the names and test the file types.  The backslashes are not necessary; only C shells don't know when to continue unless you tell them by adding backslashes.  As written, one semi-colon is superfluous, but that's pretty minor (so, at one level, are the backslashes — they do no good, but they do no harm either).